# How to open a modal with a link instead of button in Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

Is it possible to do what is described here in Vaadin?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59805709/how-to-open-the-modal-popup-using-a-link-instead-of-button

Comment: Are we talking Vaadin Flow specifically?

Comment: If it’s just for visual reasons, you might get what you need by using the "tertiary" or "tertiary-inline" button variants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to open a modal with a link instead of button in Vaadin

I must ask why? Since I think you should not do that. I recommend to copy this code to your view to see the behavior:

```
    ConfirmDialog dialog = new ConfirmDialog();
    dialog.setText("Really?");
    dialog.setConfirmText("Yes");
    dialog.addConfirmListener(e -> dialog.close());

    Button button = new Button("Open", e -> dialog.open());
    button.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_TERTIARY_INLINE);

    Anchor anchor = new Anchor("#", "Open");
    anchor.getElement().addEventListener("click", e -> dialog.open());

    add(button, anchor);
```

The both will open the dialog, yes. But clicking the anchor will also navigate back to default route "".

So if you want to get rid of the navitation you need to replace "#" with the route of the view. But it will still refresh, which you probably do not want.

If your question is purely due aesthetics, i.e. you do not want the Button to be that prominent, just use the theme variants (as in the example) and possibly some additional CSS to make it more discreet.

Comment: Can you answer a question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76845281/vaadin-payment-gateway-integration-razorpay)

Comment: ButtonVariant.LUMO_TERTIARY_INLINE is enough.